# Javascript - radio button enable/disable elements not right

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm trying to make enable/disabled elements based on the checked radio button in the edit form.

When I try to run the code and test the form, it looks kinda funny. I don't know how to explain it in words but this is the [gif that would show the problem.](https://giphy.com/gifs/glitch-radio-button-lqpbQmZK3DKQU)
It didn't enabled and disabled the elements correctly. Looks kinda funny.

I also wanted the elements to stay enabled and disabled the elements based on the checked radio button when it retrieve the values from the database but it didn't work either

This is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> Submit a Contract </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleAlert2() {
    toggleDisabled(document.getElementById("division"));
    document.getElementById("extText").disabled = false;
}
    function toggleDisabled(el) {
    try {
    el.disabled = el.disabled ? false : true;
    }
    catch(E){
    }
    if (el.childNodes && el.childNodes.length > 0) {
        for (var x = 0; x < el.childNodes.length; x++) {
        toggleDisabled(el.childNodes[x]);
        }
    }
}
function toggleAlert() {
    document.getElementById("extText").disabled = true;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        ID: 50<br>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="50" />
                    
        <label for = "client1">
        <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client1" value="Division" checked onclick="toggleAlert()"/> Division
        </label>
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
        <label for ="client2">
        <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client2" value="External"  onclick="toggleAlert2()"/> External
        </label>
        &nbsp 
        <input type="text" id="extText" name="client_details2" value="rrrrrr"/> 
        <br><br>
        
        <div id="division">
        Division:
        <select name="client_details">
            <option value="Choose"  />Choose Division...</option>
            <option value="Distribution"  />Distribution</option>
            <option value="Transmission"  />Transmission</option>
            <option value="Generation"  />Generation</option>
            <option value="Procument"  />Procument</option>
            <option value="Other"  />Others</option>
        </select>   
        <br><br>
        Others:<input type="text" name="client_details1" value="rrrrrr" />
        <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>     
</body>
```

What are the alternatives to fix my code? Thanks!

Comment: I feel like that gif belongs in a comedy show, where a old person tries to do something on a website and weird things keep happening, lol.

Comment: But the main thing that doesn't help is you posting your php along with your html code. Could you open your page, right click, hit `Page Source` and copy the html back here? Bonus points for making it into a snippet

Comment: sorry about that php thing! yeah the gif kinda looks funny! I'll post the html in a moment

Comment: @MechaMetalHead If this was working: **1A.** When 1st radio is checked, what is enabled? **1B.** What is disabled? **2A.** When 2nd radio is checked, what is enabled? **2B.** What is disabled?

Comment: Just curious, but why do you make it so complicated when your html structure is so simple? If you toggle External just disable the select and input, if you toggle Division just disable extText. There's no need for looping through childnodes.

Comment: i tried it but it didn't seems the elements were disabled, thats why i choose to write this function @A.Lau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewrite it without recursion, try-catch and setting disabled for specific div classes using querySelector().
https://jsfiddle.net/Lsre6mfL/

You can also fold

```
var divis_el = document.getElementById("division");
for (var i = 0; i < divis_el.children.length; i++) {
    divis_el.children[i].disabled = true;
}
```

In function.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, look how simple it is.

```js
function toggleAlert2() {
    document.getElementById("extText").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("client_details").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("client_details1").disabled = true;
    
}

function toggleAlert() {
    document.getElementById("extText").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("client_details").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("client_details1").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        ID: 50<br>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="50" />

        <label for = "client1">
        <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client1" value="Division" checked onchange="toggleAlert()"/> Division
        </label>
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
        <label for ="client2">
        <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client2" value="External"  onchange="toggleAlert2()"/> External
        </label>
        &nbsp 
        <input type="text" id="extText" name="client_details2" value="rrrrrr"/> 
        <br><br>

        <div id="division">
        Division:
        <select id="client_details" name="client_details">
            <option value="Choose"  />Choose Division...</option>
            <option value="Distribution"  />Distribution</option>
            <option value="Transmission"  />Transmission</option>
            <option value="Generation"  />Generation</option>
            <option value="Procument"  />Procument</option>
            <option value="Other"  />Others</option>
        </select>   
        <br><br>
        Others:<input id="client_details1" type="text" name="client_details1" value="rrrrrr" />
        <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't work so I'll be taking Унгамист Долматов's method as the code he/she gave me works. Thanks anyway. :)