# Javascript - enable/disable elements and text box based on drop down not working

Tags: javascript, html

This [code demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsre6mfL/) is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966939/javascript-radio-button-enable-disable-elements-not-right). But I wanted to make the text box enable when the value "Others" is chosen from the drop down.

This is the code that I edited from the jsfiddle.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Submit a Contract </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleExternal() {
    document.getElementById("extText").disabled = false;

    var divis_el = document.getElementById("division");
    for (var i = 0; i < divis_el.children.length; i++) {
        divis_el.children[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
function toggleDivision() {
    document.getElementById("extText").disabled = true;z
    var divis_el = document.getElementById("division");
    for (var i = 0; i < divis_el.children.length; i++) {
        divis_el.children[i].disabled = false;
    }
}

function enableTextbox() {
var val = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
if (val == 0 || val == 1 ||val == 2 ||val == 3 ||val == 4 ||) { document.getElementById("otherTxt").disabled = true}
if (val == 5) { document.getElementById("otherTxt").disabled = true; }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ID:<br>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="50" />

    <label for = "client1">
    <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client1" value="Division" checked onclick="toggleDivision()"/> Division
    </label>
    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
    <label for ="client2">
    <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client2" value="External"  onclick="toggleExternal()"/> External
    </label>
    &nbsp 
    <input disabled type="text" id="extText" name="client_details2" value=""/> 
    <br><br>

    <div id="division">
    Division:
    <select id="mySelect" name="client_details" onchange="enableTextbox()">
        <option value="Choose">Choose Division...</option>
        <option value="Distribution">Distribution</option>
        <option value="Transmission">Transmission</option>
        <option value="Generation">Generation</option>
        <option value="Procument">Procument</option>
        <option value="Other">Others</option>
    </select>   
    <br><br>
    Others:<input type="text" id="otherTxt" name="client_details1" value="" disabled/>
    <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>     
</body>
```

I added the function enableTextBox and then the disabled/enabled elements suddenly didn't work. Why is that?

Comment: Just noticed you're disabling otherTxt for any val. One should be true and the other should be false correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make 1 mistake in this line.
after **`val == 4`** you putted "or" sign "**||**" which is not allow in JS.

your second mistake is "**otherTxt**" field already disabled and you trying to disable it. so change the value "**disable = false**"

```
if (val == 0 || val == 1 ||val == 2 ||val == 3 ||val == 4) 
{
   document.getElementById("otherTxt").disabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code

```
    <html>
<head>
<title> Submit a Contract </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ID:<br>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="50" />

    <label for = "client1">
    <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client1" value="Division" checked onclick="toggleDivision()"/> Division
    </label>
    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
    <label for ="client2">
    <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client2" value="External"  onclick="toggleExternal()"/> External
    </label>
    &nbsp 
    <input disabled type="text" id="extText" name="client_details2" value=""/> 
    <br><br>

    <div id="division">
    Division:
    <select id="mySelect" name="client_details" onchange="enableTextbox()">
        <option value="Choose">Choose Division...</option>
        <option value="Distribution">Distribution</option>
        <option value="Transmission">Transmission</option>
        <option value="Generation">Generation</option>
        <option value="Procument">Procument</option>
        <option value="Other">Others</option>
    </select>   
    <br><br>
    Others:<input type="text" id="otherTxt" name="client_details1" value="" disabled/>
    <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>  
<script>
    function toggleExternal() {
        document.getElementById("extText").disabled = false;

        var divis_el = document.getElementById("division");
        for (var i = 0; i < divis_el.children.length; i++) {
            divis_el.children[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
    function toggleDivision() {
        alert('a')
        document.getElementById("extText").disabled = true;
        var divis_el = document.getElementById("division");
        for (var i = 0; i < divis_el.children.length; i++) {
            divis_el.children[i].disabled = false;
        }
    }

    function enableTextbox() {
    var val = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
    if (val == 0 || val == 1 ||val == 2 ||val == 3 ||val == 4) { document.getElementById("otherTxt").disabled = true}
    if (val == 5) { document.getElementById("otherTxt").disabled = false; }
    }
</script>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can select Others menu while clicking external and again division field, you will get others TextBox will enabled here. So this issues also fixed here. change the if condition like this. check the issue and fix it. This will helps you to better for you without issue.

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <title> Submit a Contract </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleExternal() {
        document.getElementById("extText").disabled = false;

        var divis_el = document.getElementById("division");
        for (var i = 0; i < divis_el.children.length; i++) {
            divis_el.children[i].disabled = true;
        }

    }
    function toggleDivision() {
        document.getElementById("extText").disabled = true; 
        var divis_el = document.getElementById("division");
        for (var i = 0; i < divis_el.children.length; i++) {
            divis_el.children[i].disabled = false;
        }
        var val = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
    if (val != 5 ) { document.getElementById("otherTxt").disabled = false}else{document.getElementById("otherTxt").disabled = true; }

    }

    function enableTextbox() {
    var val = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
    if (val == 0 || val == 1 ||val == 2 ||val == 3 ||val == 4 && val != 5 ) { document.getElementById("otherTxt").disabled = false}else{document.getElementById("otherTxt").disabled = true; }

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        ID:<br>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="50" />

        <label for = "client1">
        <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client1" value="Division" checked onclick="toggleDivision()"/> Division
        </label>
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
        <label for ="client2">
        <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client2" value="External"  onclick="toggleExternal()"/> External
        </label>
        &nbsp 
        <input disabled type="text" id="extText" name="client_details2" value=""/> 
        <br><br>

        <div id="division">
        Division:
        <select id="mySelect" name="client_details" onchange="enableTextbox()">
            <option value="Choose">Choose Division...</option>
            <option value="Distribution">Distribution</option>
            <option value="Transmission">Transmission</option>
            <option value="Generation">Generation</option>
            <option value="Procument">Procument</option>
            <option value="Other">Others</option>
        </select>   
        <br><br>
        Others:<input type="text" id="otherTxt" name="client_details1" value="" />
        <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>     
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's help you.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> Submit a Contract </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript">

        function clientDetails(){

            console.log(document.getElementById("client_details").value);
            if(document.getElementById("client_details").value == "Other"){
        document.getElementById("client_details1").disabled = false;
      }else{
        document.getElementById("client_details1").disabled = true;
      }
    }

    function toggleExternal() {
        document.getElementById("extText").disabled = false;
        var divis_el = document.getElementById("division");
        for (var i = 0; i < divis_el.children.length; i++) {
            divis_el.children[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
    function toggleDivision() {
        document.getElementById("extText").disabled = true;
        var divis_el = document.getElementById("division");
        for (var i = 0; i < divis_el.children.length; i++) {
            divis_el.children[i].disabled = false;
        }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        ID: 50<br>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="50" />

        <label for = "client1">
        <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client1" value="Division" checked onclick="toggleDivision()"/> Division
        </label>
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
        <label for ="client2">
        <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client2" value="External"  onclick="toggleExternal()"/> External
        </label>
        &nbsp 
        <input disabled type="text" id="extText" name="client_details2" value="rrrrrr"/> 
        <br><br>

        <div id="division">
        Division:
        <select name="client_details" id="client_details" onchange="clientDetails()">
            <option value="Choose"  />Choose Division...</option>
            <option value="Distribution"  />Distribution</option>
            <option value="Transmission"  />Transmission</option>
            <option value="Generation"  />Generation</option>
            <option value="Procument"  />Procument</option>
            <option value="Other"  />Others</option>
        </select>   
        <br><br>
        Others:<input type="text" name="client_details1" value="rrrrrr" id="client_details1" disabled/>
        <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>     
</body>
```